# How to clear data from a certain column without deleting it in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, reset

How do I clear data from a column and then set the first value as 1 with auto increment? I do not want to delete the column, merely to reset it.

edit: This is for my mysql database

Comment: The easiest is creating a new column that is auto incremented. Why do u not want to do this?

Comment: Do you want it so that when u remove a row, their is no gap in the data?

Comment: yes, I am doing for mysql table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `TRUNCATE TABLE tbl` -- will erase everything from the table
2. `ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 1`

Answer (score 1):

Do not do it.
Auto-increment column is untouchable by design.

If you reset it, you will break your application.

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE TABLE SET col=0;

UPDATE Table AS T1 SET T1.col=1+
 (SELECT MAX(T2.COL) FROM TABLE AS T2)

That should do it.